# How long was this person dead before being left?

Tags: game-of-thrones, chronology

How long was this person dead before being left?

> How much time passes between Jon Snow being killed and appearing to come back to life after everyone leaves the room in S06E02? Seems like a long time to be dead. Any comment or precedence for it in ASoIaF?

It seems like it was two days before the scene where they all leave. Did I miss anything?

Comment: It seemed like it was the next evening to me. Between 24 and 48 hours. Would need to rewatch to have any confidence in that.

Answer (score 5):

## Obviously massive spoilers for S06E01 & E02

This isn't on any book so far (we will see what happens when the sixth book comes out). On the show, we don't see a watch or calendar to know the exact times and dates, but I think we can deduce it as so:

It is night when Jon Snow is murdered (S05E10). On the next episode (S06e01), we see that there is some light coming in from the windows, so it must be the next day (~13.04)

[image]

Ser Allister gives Snow's friends until nightfall to surrender their arms (48.18):

[image]

At the end of the same episode, when Melissandre goes to sleep, it is still day outside (50.04):

[image]

So far my guess is that there have passed less that 24 hours.

On the second episode, the first scene we see with the Night's watch (wildling attack) is at night. This must be the night after the night of the murder, about 24h later (08.22):

[image]

And the final scene of the episode, where Melissandre ressurects Jon, is during the day most likely (light coming in from the windows). My guess is that it is the morning after the wildling attack (51.46):

[image]

**So, to sum it up, I would say that between Snow's death and Resurrection, about 24-36 hours have passed.**

Which would make sense:

- At night, Snow is murdered and his body is collected by friends
- The next morning, Ser Allister goes to the door of the room with the body and asks them to come out or he will kill them
- The same night Jon's friends refuse, get help from wildlings and Melissandre resurrects him the next morning.

Also, 24-36h is a reasonable amount. On the book, we learn about Lady Stoneheart, which died and several days passed before she was resurrected, and thus she couldn't talk because it was kind of too late. Snow seems okay (so far), but we'll see how well he is in the third episode.

Comment: Just to note Lady Stoneheart could not speak because of how deep the cut in her throat was, not because of how long she had been dead.

Comment: What exactly were Ser Allister's words? Did he give them until morning or one day or until the next evening, etc? Seems to me he was specific IIRC. Also...the light in the window looks like moonlight to me.

Comment: @Joshua Ser Allister gives them until nightfall to surrender their arms; I've updated my answer. Also, which window light are you referring to as moonlight? All of them seem pretty bright to me, that's why I said it's the sun, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Skooba I read the book years back, so I'm not 100% sure, but wasn't the case that Beric could only partially heal her because she was dead for a few days?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic When Melissandre goes to bed. Seemed to me she was going to bed the same night Jon was killed, just late. A full moon is very bright in the country night sky.