# Do any lords of the Northern Houses know this character returned from the dead?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Contains **possible spoilers for Winds of Winter and beyond**, based on events from the Game of Thrones TV series which might happen in future books.

---

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/why-isnt-jon-executed-on-sight) about whether...

> Jon Snow should get executed for deserting the Night's Watch

...got me thinking. Maybe they wouldn't be quick to pass that judgement if they knew the character had died and later been resurrected.

In the TV show, Stark loyalists go to the lords of various northern houses asking for support against Ramsay Bolton. Do any members of the Manderlys, the Mormonts, and the Glovers know about the resurrection?

In the meeting at Winterfell after the battle scene in episode 9 of season 6, there would be opportunities for them to hear stories of the character's resurrection from those who had been witnesses (wildlings, Ser Davos, etc...). Therefore I don't want answers based on events after the battle, but before the battle when they don't have a chance to ask those directly involved. When the character  goes around asking for help, if the Northern Lords had heard, that might affect their view.

**In the books**, do any of the northern lords know about this returning from the dead?

Did any messenger ravens go out with this news? Did people spread stories about someone who came back to life?

Comment: He hasn't been resurrected in the books (yet), unfortunately, so we don't know. :(

Comment: Why have you added the `game-of-thrones` tag then asked about the books?

Comment: One of the most shameless spoilers I've ever seen. (I've read all of the books, haven't watched any of the TV series.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I've fixed it for you, the TV show is worth watching but don't expect it to be too faithful to the books, especially in it's later seasons.

Comment: None of the preview chapters I have seen make any reference to this event either :-/

Answer (score 2):

## Game of Thrones

In the show I don't think any messages were sent out about his death and considering he was [wasn’t dead for very long (estimated around 1-3 days)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127306/58193) before being brought back it's unlikely. Since then we've lost any appearance of events at the Wall and Jon has been busy with other things. However, I don't think Jon or anyone close to him has broke the news yet considering he stopped Davos telling Dany.

> Davos Seaworth: All those things you don't believe in, he faced those things. He fought those things for the good of his people. He risked his life for his people. He took a knife in the heart for his people. He gave his own --
>   *Jon Snow looks at Davos Seaworth to cut him off. Davos Seaworth stops talking. Daenerys Targaryen and Tyrion Lannister exchange glances.*
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 3, "The Queens Justice"</sub>

However, Jon was the Lord Commander and the Maesters keep record of them so it's possible a raven was dispatched to them. To counter that again though no raven was sent when Jeor died and they weren't informed of Maester Aemons death either or of Jon Snow becoming Lord Commander and Sam to become the new Maester.

> Samwell Tarly: I’m-- I’m to be the new maester.
>   Maester: Oh. According to our records, Jeor Mormont is Lord Commander.
>   Samwell Tarly: He died.
>   Maester: We received no report from the maester at Castle Black.
>   Samwell Tarly: Maester Aemon became quite ill shortly after the election. He’s since passed away. Which is why I’m here.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 10, "The Winds of Winter"</sub>

## A Song of Ice and Fire

Jon is yet to be resurrected, if at all, in the books. The last we see of him is when he is stabbed over and over, much like the show.

> Jon fell to his knees. He found the dagger's hilt and wrenched it free. In the cold night air the wound was smoking. "Ghost," he whispered. Pain washed over him. Stick them with the pointy end. When the third dagger took him between the shoulder blades, he gave a grunt and fell face-first into the snow. He never felt the fourth knife. Only the cold …
>   <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Jon XIII</sub>

Seeing as that's the last POV chapter we have of Jon, for obvious reasons, and is one of the last chapters in the book with only a Barristan Selmy, Daenerys Targaryen and Kevan Lannister chapter afterwards we don't know what's happened at the Wall since.

Comment: Wasn't he dead for a bit more than 24 hours in the show? It was around bedtime when he was killed, then the siege of the body started the next day, and I thought they were going to come at down the day after the siege started to break down the door.

Comment: @ToddWilcox estimates put it at 1-3 days, I’ll edit that part to be more accurate but the point was mainly it was a short time span